# python subprocess even with exceptions return non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following code:

```
while True:
    try:
       cmd = input("-> ")
       cmdoutput = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, text=True, errors='ignore', timeout=2, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
       print(cmdoutput)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                        print(e.output)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                        print('timeout error')
```

Works fine with all commands but when running `cat` on an image file the program exit with:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cat image.jpg' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

If i run the `cat image.jpg` on a real terminal i get an long list of random characters.

Is there any way to stop that? i tried the `subprocess.SubprocessError` but nothing.

Comment: Can we see the terminal output?

Comment: the output: https://i.imgur.com/e16DnsR.png

Comment: If i do cat /bin/ls for example i wont any error

Comment: Have you tried using this program to call "cat /bin/ls"? Does that work?

Comment: yea i wont get any error, only happens when i do with images

Comment: Simple Solution: Don't use it with images, my guess is that the confusing output of a binary (image) file is making subprocess think there is an error. Also "cat" was designed for text files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253606/discussion-between-thetridentguy-and-inj3ct0r).

Comment: @Inj3ct0r please put that information in your post, including showing the actual command invocation, since that's a detail that [should be in your question](/help/how-to-ask). Also, since `cat image.jpg` needs to run in the correct directory, what happens when you use the absolute path for that image as argument to `cat`, so that "the directory your script runs in" no longer plays a role? (And whether that works or not, remember to update your post to say what happens so that your post continued to contain all the details)

Comment: In general, I would expect a process that throws an exception to exit non-zero.

Comment: If the command `cat image.jpg` failed (which is all that "returned non-zero exit status 1` really means), it almost certainly printed an error message that explained the reason.   But it looks like you are not allowing that error message to be written to the error stream, so you can't see it.